# Strict Notice: Non-static method should not be called statically

Tags: php, magento

I'm getting this error in magento log:

> Strict Notice: Non-static method
>   Mage_Catalog_Block_Product::getPriceHtml() should not be called
>   statically, assuming $this from incompatible context  in
>   /home/edistico/domains/fujitsu-skener.si/public_html/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/callforprice/callforprice_simple.phtml
>   on line 23

This is callforprice_simple.phtml:

```
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct() ?>

<?php
// RM: Dobimo attribut
$prodBuyType = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getProductBuyType();
?>
<?php  if ($_product->isAvailable()): ?>
<p class="availability in-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Availability:') ?> <span>
<?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('zaloga') ?></span></p>
<?php else: ?>    <p class="availability out-of-stock">
<?php echo $this->__('Availability:') ?> <span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p><?php  endif; ?>
<?php   echo $this->getChildHtml('product_type_data_extra') ?>

<?php $model=Mage::getModel('callforprice/callforprice')->loadByProductId($_product->getId());

if ($prodBuyType != 1) {
    if ($model->getId() && $model->getStatus()==1) {?>
    <div class="call-for-price"><?php echo "<font size=3><strong>" .$this->__($model->getValue()). "</strong></font>";?></div>
    <?php } else {
        echo Mage_Catalog_Block_Product::getPriceHtml($_product);
    }
} else {
    echo Mage_Catalog_Block_Product::getPriceHtml($_product);
}

?>
```

This is class:

```
<?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magentocommerce.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magentocommerce.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    Mage
 * @package     Mage_Catalog
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2012 Magento Inc. (http://www.magentocommerce.com)
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 */


class Mage_Catalog_Block_Product extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    protected $_finalPrice = array();

    public function getProduct()
    {
        if (!$this->getData('product') instanceof Mage_Catalog_Model_Product) {
            if ($this->getData('product')->getProductId()) {
                $productId = $this->getData('product')->getProductId();
            }
            if ($productId) {
                $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
                if ($product) {
                    $this->setProduct($product);
                }
            }
        }
        return $this->getData('product');
    }

    public function getPrice()
    {
        return $this->getProduct()->getPrice();
    }

    public function getFinalPrice()
    {
        if (!isset($this->_finalPrice[$this->getProduct()->getId()])) {
            $this->_finalPrice[$this->getProduct()->getId()] = $this->getProduct()->getFinalPrice();
        }
        return $this->_finalPrice[$this->getProduct()->getId()];
    }

    public function getPriceHtml($product)
    {
        $this->setTemplate('catalog/product/price.phtml');
        $this->setProduct($product);
        return $this->toHtml();
    }
}
```

Can I ask for some help?

Thanks

Comment: `getPriceHtml` is not defined as a static method for `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product` class and you're calling it as static which is not allowed

Comment: Ok, I got that, how can I repair it?

Comment: Can you show us that class? Or you can simply make that method static under class declaration

Comment: Is it possible just to call getPriceHtml static from phtml I posted? I'm beginer beginer in PHP ... :)

Answer (score 0):

`Mage_Catalog_Block_Product::getPriceHtml($_product);`

you need to first create an instance of class `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product(using factory method get Model)` and then call function `Model->getPriceHtml($_product);`

Comment: I'm totally new at PHP, can you tell me exactly how to do that?

Comment: Magento needs PHP expertise.I strongly recommend to first get basic PHP concept clear.Magento uses lots of advanced concept and design patterns.